# How do a val to put an image in

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I need some help because I create a recyclerView, and I put in some text like this :
`data class MuscleModel(val name: String, val description: String)`.
After I create in my HomeFragment

```
        val muscleList = arrayListOf<MuscleModel>()
        muscleList.add(MuscleModel(
                "bas des jambes",
                "chevilles, mollets, jambiers…"))
```

It works. But I would also put images, can I use the same system ? And if it is the case, how should I do ? I have the pictures in my Drawable resources. But I don't find the right type of val in my Model for put an Image that I have already. I know how to do with a http link but it isn't what I need.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Resources have Int IDs, so add a property that's an Int and you can set it to `R.drawable.whatever`.

Comment: Can you explain with example because I am a rookie in programmation @Tenfour04 please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an Int property for your drawable resource. You can optionally mark it `@DrawableRes` to clarify what it's for and cause the compiler to warn you if you pass the wrong type of value.

```
data class MuscleModel(
    val name: String, 
    val description: String, 
    val drawable: Int
)

// or

data class MuscleModel(
    val name: String, 
    val description: String, 
    @DrawableRes val drawable: Int
)
```

When you use this class, you can pass a drawable ID:

```
val myMuscleModel = MuscleModel("Hello", "world", R.drawable.my_muscle_picture)
```

In your adapter's `onBindView` you can set the image:

```
val item = data[position]
holder.myImageView.setDrawableResource(item.drawable)
```

Comment: And with that code done, how can I implement multiple images, because that's the aim ?  Should I simply create multiple :           
'val myMuscleModel = MuscleModel("Hello", "world", R.drawable.my_muscle_picture)' ?
Thank you :)

Comment: If you're working with a RecyclerView, presumably you have multiple of these MuscleModel instances. How you create them is going to depend on where they're coming from (static resources, a database, or from the network, etc.)